# google map with multiple location

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have website display list of jobs results and I have search criteria by location to display this jobs in the specific location

the client can select multiple location to search

I want put live google maps with markers showing where the jobs results are.

Map to be centered around the most accurate result.

but the problem if the client searched by more than one location as London and Guildford how I can display this google maps ,what is the parameter I should send to google map?

can anyone help me how I can display the results of the jobs be pinned on the map at the same time with multiple location ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="/Sources/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
<div class="infobox">your box here</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function () {
        var windowH = $(window).height();
        $('#map').css({ 'height': (windowH) + 'px' });
    });

    var locations = 
    [
        ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856],
        ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        scrollwheel: false,
        zoom: 13,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    });

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            map.setCenter(initialLocation);
        });
    }

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: $('.infobox').html(),
        disableAutoPan: false,
        maxWidth: 200,
        alignBottom: true,
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(35, 120),
        zIndex: null,
        boxStyle: {
            background: "#ffffff",
            width: "300px"
        },
        closeBoxURL: "",
        infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
    });

    var marker, i;
    var image = '/Sources/images/marker.png';
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

//include google map link and google map div id "map"

```
  var map = null;
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var locations = 
    [
        ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, "Bondi Beach Jobs"], // display content place 3rd element
        ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, "Coogee Beach Jobs"] // display content place 3rd element
    ];
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.890542, 151.274856),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;

setTimeout(function () {
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  //set location with address
  if(locations[i][0] != "") {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) { //getPosition().toUrlValue(6)
    return function() {
        // display content place 3rd element
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][3] + "<br>coordinates: " + marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));

  }

}
},1000);
```